# Inconsistent result from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object via sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

From SQL Server Management Studio, I ran the following query, which is trying to execute dynamic queries (via `sp_executesql`) which get metadata about some stored procedures (using `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object`):

```sql
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500) = N'SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID(@ProcName), NULL)';
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500) = N'@ProcName NVARCHAR(500)';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @ProcName = '[sys].[xxxxxxxx]';   -- query 1
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @ProcName = '[sys].[sp_indexes]'; -- query 2
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @ProcName = '[sys].[xxxxxxxx]';   -- query 3
```

Notice that queries 1 and 3 are identical (both referencing an inexistent procedure), so I expect them to return the same result. However, surprisingly, while query 1 gave an error as expected, query 3 gave the same response as query 2!

Why is that?

Notes:

1. I tried that on:

   - SQL Server 2017 on Windows Server
   - SQL Server 2017 in Docker

     ```sh
     docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
     ```
   - SQL Server 2019 in Docker

     ```sh
     docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
     ```

   The behaviour is the same in all 3 cases.
2. There's no such problem if I don't use dynamic queries. That is, if I run:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID('[sys].[xxxxxxxx]'), NULL)   -- query 1
   SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID('[sys].[sp_indexes]'), NULL) -- query 2
   SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID('[sys].[xxxxxxxx]'), NULL)   -- query 3
   ```

   As expected, queries 1 and 3 give an error, while query 2 gives the result.

Comment: Seems to be oddness with plan caching. A workaround is to add the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` hint: `DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500) = N'SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID(@ProcName), NULL) OPTION(RECOMPILE)';`